# Disabling create feature when create request is made using GET in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I started tinkering with Sails.js recently and I wish to use it for production for my projects and as a mobile backend. In Sails.js docs, in the blueprint api it says that the create method call should be of POST type here https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/create.

But even with GET request, record gets created. How to disable create feature when the request is of GET type..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @paulogdm, I was surprised that your GET was creating records. But I found the doc - it is a "shortcut" route in sails, and can be disabled. The docs are [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints).

In your `/config/blueprints.js` file, you need to add:

```
module.exports = {

    // ...
    shortcuts: false

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed it. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely disable the BLUEPRINT API, you might take a look at `config/blueprints.js`.
But you can create a police to just limit the access of it by doing something like this in 'policies.js':

```
UserController : {
    'thisispublic' : true,
    'thisisnot' : false,
    'create' : ['hasAdminToken'],
    'update' : ['hasAdminToken'],
    'destroy' : ['hasAdminToken'],
}
```

Note that some actions are implied in the controller - even if you dont have a "create" function, it will be there provided by your model when it exists...

Comment: Thanks very much. By the way, I don't want to remove the create route, simply don't want to allow it with a get request.

Comment: Oh I see... Thats really strange because the Sails documentation states: 
`  *  GET /boat -> BoatController.find                                        *
  *  GET /boat/:id -> BoatController.findOne                                 *
  *  POST /boat -> BoatController.create                                     *
  *  PUT /boat/:id -> BoatController.update                                  *
  *  DELETE /boat/:id -> BoatController.destroy    
`